# Star Wars Armada: does a squadron command give a squadron an extra turn?

Tags: star-wars-armada

When I move / fire one or more squadrons using the squadron command of a ship do the squadrons still get to move / fire in the squadron phase or is their activation over for the round?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Squadrons only activate once per turn**

Per the [Armada Rules Reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/2c/4d/2c4de555-925d-4fde-8af6-02873437149b/swm01_rules_reference_guide_lowres.pdf) on page 12, squadrons *Activate* when one of these happens:

- In the Squadron Phase (with the limit of either Moving or Attacking, but not both)
- In the Ship Phase when a ship resolves a [squadron] command (with the ability to both move *and* attack)

But at the end of any activation you toggle the Activation Slider for the squadron to indicate that it has been activated.

Further, you cannot activate a squadron if the color of its Activation Slider does not match the Initiative Token. This includes squadrons with the *Rogue* keyword as that keyword applies when they *Activate*.

The net result of this is that you can *either* activate during the Ship Phase or during the Squadron Phase, but not both.